# VB.net - Sorting only one column in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm populating a `DataGridView` from an Excel file, and trying to sort only ONE column of my choice, other columns should remain as-is. How can it be achieved? Should the component be changed to something else, in case it is not possible in `DataGridView`?

Comment: Update your question with code showing exactly extracting this data from Excel and how you are populating your DataGridView.  Answers will depend on the methods you've used here

Comment: Copy the data from that column into an array or collection, sort that, then copy it back into the column. The grid is not going to do it for you and neither is the data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Created a List of my custom class, and this class will handle the sorting based on my preference (Randomization in this case)

```vb
Public Class Mylist
    Implements IComparable(Of Mylist)

    Private p_name As String
    Private r_id As Integer

    Public Property Pname() As String    'This will hold the contents of DGV that I want sorted
        Get
            Return p_name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            p_name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Rid() As Integer    'This will be the basis of sort
        Get
            Return r_id
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            r_id = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Function IComparable_CompareTo(other As Mylist) As Integer Implements IComparable(Of Mylist).CompareTo
        If other Is Nothing Then
            Return 1
        Else
            Return Me.Rid.CompareTo(other.Rid)
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

Then a Button which will sort the contents:

```vb
            Dim selcol = xlView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
            Dim rand = New Random()
            Dim x As Integer = 0
            Dim plist As New List(Of Mylist)

            Do While x < xlView.Rows.Count
                plist.Add(New Mylist() With {
                .Pname = xlView.Rows(x).Cells(selcol).Value,
                .Rid = rand.Next()
                })
                x += 1
            Loop
            plist.Sort()
            x = 0
            Do While x < xlView.Rows.Count
                xlView.Rows(x).Cells(selcol).Value = plist.ElementAt(x).Pname
                x += 1
            Loop
            xlView.Update()
            plist.Clear()
```

I'm open to any changes to code, as long as it achieves the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simpler version. Pass the column index will do like Call SortSingleColum(0)

```
 Private Sub SortSingleColumn(x As Integer)

        Dim DataCollection As New List(Of String)

        For i = 0 To dgvImport.RowCount - 2
            DataCollection.Add(dgvImport.Item(x, i).Value)
        Next

        Dim t As Integer = 0
        For Each item As String In DataCollection.OrderBy(Function(z) z.ToString)
            dgvImport.Item(x, t).Value = item
            t = t + 1
        Next



    End Sub
```